# fat free php in subdirectory, routes not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, fat-free-framework

I'm staging a fatfree site, but I'm having an issue with it running in a subdirectory

this is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /~site/index.php [L,QSA]
```

and this is the route I'm using

```
GET /*/index=App->show_home
```

I'm having to add the `/*` before the rest of it, because the script keeps including the subfolder as part of the route.

this is working, I suppose, but once I update the dns settings, the site will no longer have these and I have to update it.

Is there a setting that I can apply somewhere that would allow both scenarios to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic required .htaccess goes like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Notice how:

- RewriteBase is not needed
- index.php is located in the same folder as .htaccess

But when using mod_userdir, a little more configuration is required:

1. Set RewriteBase explicitly (as you did): `RewriteBase /~myuser/`
2. In the user directory Apache configuration, make sure that `FollowSymlinks` and `AllowOverride All` are enabled. They respectively allow the `~` link to be followed and .htaccess to be processed.

Here's an example of a user directory Apache configuration:

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

To answer your last question:

> Is there a setting that I can apply somewhere that would allow both scenarios to work?

The answer is: no, as long as you're serving the website from a user directory. Move your website to the `DocumentRoot` and everything will run smoothly.